# LPADing for JOINS

Tags: sql, join, teradata, padding

I want to join 2 tables A and B on their ID. Table A's ID has 12 digits while Table B's ID can be from 0 to 12 digits. I tried using LPAD but its taking too long and I am not sure whether it will work. Any advice?

```
SELECT*

FROM table a
LEFT JOIN table b
ON a.ID = LPAD(b.ID,12,'0')
```

Comment: What data types are the two columns? Sample data would be helpful.

Comment: I am not sure numbers or strings.
Example: 099486219621 in a.ID and 99486219621 in b.ID

Comment: The really short answer is yes, that logic should work for the join. You'd need to add DDL for both tables and your explain plan for the performance problems.  But you'd be a lot better off storing the data the same way in both tables.

Comment: Its taking hours and still not done even when I added the following:
WHERE a.ID='099486219621'

Comment: You need to supply more info. What's the row count of both tables and the actual data types (use SHOW TABLE). Switching the calculation to table a might help: `on cast(a.ID as int) = b.ID`

Comment: ID is a tracking number of a package, there are too many rows.

Comment: Why are the data types different? This is really bad, especially for big tables. You still didn't add needed info, row cunts & data types, and what's the PI of those tables?